# How to show data from database in QTableView using some condition

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

I am a beginner in Qt programming and I am working on a project in which I am using SQLite database.

I have 20 rows in my database and I just want to show last five rows in `QTableView` when I press show button first time. If I then press the show button a second time, the last 10 rows should be shown from the database.

But I don't have any idea what codes I should write. Please help me.

look at this image I just want to display last five rows when I click show button first time and then I want to display 10 last rows when I click show button the second time.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code to show the data from SQLite database into `QTableView`.

```
void SecondWindow::on_pushButton_show_clicked()
{
    MainWindow conn;
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
    conn.openConn();
    QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
    qry->prepare("select eid,name,surname,salary from employeeInfo");
    qry->exec();
    model->setQuery(*qry);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    conn.closeConn();
    qDebug() << (model->rowCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the **LIMIT** keyword in your SQL query, e.g.:

```
"select eid,name,surname,salary from employeeInfo LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10"
```

will return 10 rows after the first 10.

Comment: No, I just want to know what condition should I use for this.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to send SQL query every time, but just change number of displayed elements, you may write [`QAbstractProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html)-based model class. You'll only need to override `mapFromSource`, `mapToSource` and `rowCount` methods

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: how I can show data from the database as my requirement.

Comment: @AshuAnsari, as the name suggests, proxy model just maps elements from source model (`QSqlQueryModel` in your case).